# Return Image from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm using an odbc connection to connect to an SQL server. I need to display all the fields below:

- **Name:** ID
  **Type:** tinyint
- **Name:** GroupId
   **Type:** smallint
- **Name:** Photo
  **Type:** image

I'm using the code below which obviously isn't working:

```
<?php

$serverName = "TESTSERV\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$database = "test";
$user = "sa";
$password="@r@g0nSQLS@";
$DSN_TEST="TESTSERV - TEST";
$DSN_InetDb="TESTSERV - InetDb";
$DSN_taclog="TESTSERV-TACLOG";
$DSN_general="odbc-test";
$conn_TEST = odbc_connect ($DSN_TEST, $user, $password);
$conn_InetDb = odbc_connect($DSN_InetDb, $user, $password);
$conn_taclog = odbc_connect($DSN_taclog, $user, $password);
$conn_general=odbc_connect($DSN_general, $user, $password);

//confirming connectivity
if ($conn_general){
    echo ('Connected'.'<br>');
}
else{
    echo ('Not connected');
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM InetDb.dbo.IndivImages WHERE IndivNdx = 30";
$sql_run = odbc_exec($conn_general,$sql);
$row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_run,3);
echo'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['UserImage']).'">';
?>
```

When executing this code, images are replaced with a chunk of characters.
How would I be able to return the images instead of a random characters ?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: where and how are you trying to echo the images?

Comment: using odbc_result_all, which from my basic knowledge should 'echo' the result of an odbc_exec command

Comment: You need some form of `img src` or header. See the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

You won't end up with actual images if you just echo out binary -- or base64-encoded -- data you've stored in the database. You'll just get the raw data blurted out.

If your images are stored as binary data, you need to serve it out via a script that outputs an image header -- e.g. `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` -- followed by echoing out the raw data. You would then link to it e.g. as `<img src="imager.php?img_id=124123123..." />`. You could pass the data between your script and the "imager" e.g. over a `$_SESSION` variable.

If your images are stored as base64-encoded data (or if you convert the raw data on the fly), you can also use `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,foBar1Nwht3v5R..." />`. Be aware though that this isn't exactly bandwidth-friendly, and is better reserved for icons etc. rather than large image files.

Third option is to simply write the image data to the filesystem and then link to it with a standard img tag. That would make your images more easily cacheable, too. (There are ways around to ensure caching with the above options too, but writing them out, even into a /tmp directory if they are not reused, may be a simpler approach, and also save you some database performance.)

Comment: Thanks @Markun AO. I've added header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); to the code however I'm not sure what you mean pass the data between your script and the imager over $_session.

Apologies for I'm not a developer by professions.

Comment: Doing that will not magically make your images appear as images. A header defines everything that is output after it by your script. You need to realize that HTML can be output as it is, while images are not made up of HTML, but of binary or base64-encoded data. That image data needs to be contained in something. Whether you use a separate file that echo-s out the image data, or whether a base64-encoded image tag. In any case you will need to use an `<img src="to-the-image" />` tag pointing to the image, if you hope to show images on your HTML page.

Comment: I've update the code and copied it to the question as suggested by yourself, however I get the broken image icon when loading the page. Can you help with the syntax please ? Sorry for easy requests but I'm still trying to understand development.

Comment: What you do above presumes that it's a JPEG image and that the image data in your database table is a binary representation of the image. (And not e.g. already base64-encoded.) How do you input the images to begin with?

Comment: It's input through another system automatically.

Comment: You need to verify what format the other system provides the images in.